# Trimming of poorly performing employees

Tags: idioms

I'd like to understand what does it mean "trimming of poorly performing workers" - Does it mean firing them or some type of punishment?

Comment: Was poorly-performing hyphenated in the original? It gets very ambiguous without one; sounds like they're trimming 'performing workers' who are ill ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb [to trim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trim) means, "to remove by or as if by cutting," so this certainly means to remove workers by firing them.  Frequently, "trimming" specifically means "removing wasteful or useless things or people" and "trimming the fat" is a well-known and frequently-used metaphor for cutting spending, including by firing employees.

Comment: To trim can mean to reduce in length or size by cutting, trim a hedge, trim my hair, trim my dog's coat, for example. I hope they aren't going to do that to the poorly performing workers. If so, I am glad I live and work in Britain, where we have Employment Tribunals.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The Yakuza were known for cutting off a finger joint of those who failed at a task. While I know that's not the meaning here, I couldn't help but be reminded of it when *punishment* came up in the question . . .